# Is there a way to create two connections to the same database with different users in quarkus?

Tags: mysql, datasource, quarkus

Is there a way to create two connections to the same database with different users in quarkus. I know about the named datasources concept but it only works if both datasources are different db altogether. Is it possible to connect to same DB using different datasource properties. I am getting follow error when I tried with "named datasources" :`WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource 'app': Communications link failure`

```
quarkus.datasource."app".db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource."app".username=read_only_user
quarkus.datasource."app".password=read_only_user
quarkus.datasource."app".jdbc.url=<url>

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=default
quarkus.datasource.password=default
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=<url>
```

// dao layer using the read_only_user datasource

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Dao {

  @Inject
  @PersistenceUnit("app")
  EntityManager em;
```

// default

```
 @ApplicationScoped
    public class Dao2 {
    
      @Inject
      EntityManager em;
```

used the documentation as my reference https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource

Comment: You said "I know about the named datasources concept but it only works if both datasources are different db altogether", but is not  true.

Comment: If we have the same URL for default and the named datasource but different username and password it doesn't work.

Comment: What problem do you get?

Comment: WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource 'app': Communications link failure -this is the error. I went with another solution for my issue, but it would be great to know that this can work.

Comment: If this does not work, it's a bug

Comment: What would you suggest here, shall I open a bug with quarkus?

Comment: Yes, exactly...